# Event Space axiom questions

Tags: probability-theory

S: Sample space

F: the event space

---

(1.2)  F is non empty

(1.3)  If A is an element of F, then its complement is in F

(1.4) If A1, A2 , A3, ... are elements of F, then the 
UNION I=1 to infinity of Ai is an element of F.

---

*Sorry for the lack of notation. Still need to learn how to use symbols.

In axiom (1.4) is it telling me that I am required to take a complete union of every set in F in order to have its union part of F ?  For example, if I had 4 total sets, and took the union of them , the result would be in F. But if I took the union of 2 out of the 4 sets it may or may not be in F..?

I played around with event space examples and found I always found the union of 2 out of 4( or whatever total ) sets in the event space.

Reworded question: Is axiom (1.4) telling me I can take just a few sets of the space and have its union in F as well?

---

There are some results from these axioms that make sense to me if you dont need all the sets. The sample space is an element of the event space result. And the intersection ( similar to 1.4) result.

Comment: Im using Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition oxford pdf found in google search. Id post a picture of the page but I cant.

Comment: You've encountered one of the unpleasant aspects of the English language. "$A_1,A_2,\dots$ are elements of $F$" means only that these $A_i$'s are some, not necessarily all, of the elements of $F$. But if one inserts a definite article, "$A_1,A_2,\dots$ are the elements of $F$" would ordinarily mean that the $A_i$'s are all of the elements of $F$.

Comment: Thank you. That really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of stating the axiom in question is that F is closed under countable union - so the union of *any* finite or countable collection of sets in F also has to be in F.

Thus no, the union does not have to be all the sets.